# How to use a Linux "platform_driver"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

There is an embedded system, and it provides functions in a struct of `platform_driver`:

```
static struct platform_driver infinity_wdt_driver = {
    .probe      = infinity_wdt_probe,
    .remove     = infinity_wdt_remove,
    .shutdown   = infinity_wdt_shutdown,
    .driver     = {
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .name   = "infinity-wdt",
        .of_match_table = ms_watchdog_of_match_table,
    },
};

module_platform_driver(infinity_wdt_driver);
```

In the `infinity_wdt_probe` it calls `devm_kzalloc` and `devm_ioremap_resource`:

```
static int infinity_wdt_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) {
  ...
  wdt = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, sizeof(*wdt), GFP_KERNEL);
  ...
  wdt->reg_base = devm_ioremap_resource(&pdev->dev, res);
  ...
}
```

How shall I utilize this driver? Do I need to write some C code, or Linux provides some standard way through filesystem for controlling this?

In the filesystem there is a directory under `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/infinity-wdt`, but it contains only a few files:

```
# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Nov 16 20:23 1f006000.watchdog -> ../../../../devices/soc0/soc/1f006000.watchdog
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Nov 16 20:23 bind
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Nov 16 20:23 uevent
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Nov 16 20:23 unbind
```

Is it somehow possible to use the driver with this filesystem above?

Some extra info: `1f006000.watchdog` is a symlink to a directory which contains these:

```
# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Nov 16 20:23 driver -> ../../../../bus/platform/drivers/infinity-wdt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Nov 16 20:23 driver_override
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Nov 16 20:23 modalias
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Nov 16 20:23 of_node -> ../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/soc/watchdog
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Nov 16 20:23 subsystem -> ../../../../bus/platform
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Nov 16 20:23 uevent
```

This is the kernel log:

```
# cat /var/log/messages | grep -i watchdog
Jan  1 04:00:02 kernel: [WatchDog]infinity_wdt_probe 
Jan  1 04:00:02 kernel: [WatchDog]infinity_wdt_set_heartbeat 
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: [WatchDog]infinity_wdt_start 
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: [WatchDog] infinity_wdt_ping tmr_margin=a ^M
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: [WatchDog] infinity_wdt_ping tmr_margin=a ^M
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: [WatchDog]infinity_wdt_set_timeout=60 
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: [WatchDog]infinity_wdt_set_timeout data=3c ^M
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: [WatchDog] infinity_wdt_ping tmr_margin=3c ^M
Jan  1 04:00:04 kernel: [WatchDog] infinity_wdt_ping tmr_margin=3c ^M
Nov 16 21:03:11 kernel: [WatchDog] infinity_wdt_ping tmr_margin=3c ^M
Nov 16 21:03:41 kernel: [WatchDog] infinity_wdt_ping tmr_margin=3c ^M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Platform" driver means driver that doesn't fit into other standard subsystem (e.g. USB, I2C, etc). In this case it's a watchdog driver, which is apparently supposed to reboot embedded system if it's not responsive.

Entries in sysfs are standard bookkeeping entries, automatically created for any driver by kernel.

Since driver contains "of_match_table", it implies that it must be correctly specified in the device tree. Given it generally works and has no other explicit interfaces (e.g. procfs, sysfs), this should be enough to enable it.

You might also check if corresponding /dev/watchdog* is created by this driver. If so, standard userspace watchdog can be used by specified this /dev/watchdog* file in its config file.

Comment: How can I check if `/dev/watchdog*` is created by this driver or not? I have two files: `watchdog` and `watchdog0`. Also attached my kernel log. The problem is that in spite of the device is unresponsive, this watchdog seems not rebooting the device.

Comment: If this driver is a module, you might try unloading it via rmmod, and see what happens (if board reboots, device disappears, etc).

Alternatively, look for 'watchdog_register_device' in driver source code. If it's there, likely one of these is created by this driver.

Comment: No it's built into kernel. Should I rebuild it with 'M' and unload it to check?

Comment: That should work, may be just disable it completely and see if device is gone.

Comment: Neither `watchdog` file remained in `/dev` after removing that platform-specific watchdog feature from the kernel. Good. Now I realized my real problem: wdt seems being active while the filesystem is stalled. As the kernel is loaded, wdt won't reboot the system. Do you know how can I manually control the watchdog through the `/dev/watchdog*`?

Comment: man watchdog and googling "kernel watchdog API" should help